# How to set submit button to display using post method with name with different ids based on its database

Tags: php, html, sql

This is my query. I want to display the submit button with name depending on its ID.

```
                <?php

                 $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tb_topic");
                 while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
                     $t_id = $row['t_id'];
                     $t_title = $row['t_title'];
                     $t_desc = $row['t_desc'];

                     echo "<a class='list-group-item'><input type='submit' name='$t_id' class='submitLink' value='$t_title'></a>";

                 }

                 ?>
```

Now i want to display the data using the ID from the link.

```
             <?php
              if($_POST['$t_id']){
                  echo "$";

               $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tb_topic WHERE t_id='$t_id'");
             while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){

                 $t_title = $row['t_title'];
                 $t_desc = $row['t_desc'];

                echo $t_title;
                echo $t_desc;
                }   


              ?>
```

is this possible?

i can make it display if i use:

```
                     <?php
                      if($_POST['1']){
                          echo "1";}    

                      if($_POST['2']){
                          echo "2";`*enter code here*`

                      }
                      ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes use variable variables

```
<?php
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
    ${$key} = $value; 
    // or something like
    if(${$key} == "1"){
        // do something
    }
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: Salute sir, Thanks!